# How to enable location in chrome for a local domain.test site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am running a laravel project with this domain `http://dfood.test/` in my locally. When I was trying to try location, I see Crhome blocked it.

See this image please 
[image]

How can I enable it?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can manage allowed/blocked list from this url: chrome://settings/content/location

Comment: you need to enable https for location services https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: @Pamirzameen it's by default blocked. I cannot see the the site in the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accessing location is allowed in https only. But it's allowed for domains such as '.localhost' or '.example'.

Comment: Thanks. .localhost works. Didn't know google registered it.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean **How to enabling the microphone, location, camera in Chrome for localhost** you can follow these steps :

[My google chrome settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6hMg.png)

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` in Chrome.
2. Find and enable the `Insecure origins treated as secure` section (see below).
3. Add any addresses you want to ignore the secure origin policy for. Remember to include the port number too (if required).
4. Save and restart Chrome.